# How to parametrize Maven surefire plugin so I can choose which TestNG suites to run

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I've got many test suites in TestNG. These are XML files. I want to be able to choose multiple XML suites when running integration-test from maven.

Currently I can add the suite files to pom.xml like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>${pathToMySuiteFile_1}</suiteXmlFile>
      <suiteXmlFile>${pathToMySuiteFile_1}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This solution has some limitations. I can only change a path to the test suite I've got defined in pom.xml. So in my example it always has to be two files. I'm not able to run, lets say, 5 suites or just one.

Is there a way to somehow parametrize the whole section "suiteXmlFiles" in pom.xml ?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
      ${multiple_paths_ToMySuiteFiles}
    </suiteXmlFiles>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Running everything that matches given test group is not an option for me:
I don't want to load all the suites I've got and then run just the selected tests using groups in TestNG suite. The reason being that a report that gets generated after running all the test suites with group filters is different from a report when just the selected test suites were run.

Answer (score 22):

According to [User Property](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#suiteXmlFiles) of `suiteXmlFiles` You can use:

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=test1.xml,test2.xml
```

Comment: Using this solution, you don't need to specify the <suiteXmlFiles> tag in the pom.xml file. Best answer.

Comment: with this one I get error `[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".suiteXmlFiles=test1.xml,test2.xml". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.`

Comment: No doubt it is the best answer, I was struggling for some days with same issue. With this, it is resolved now. Thanks @Sam

Answer (score 10):

We also hit this issue with our tests.
The current workaround that we use now is to define a property variable in the property section and inject it in sure-fire suiteXmlFiles block.

```
<properties>
    <!-- Default suites -->
    <batsSuiteFile>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/BatsTests.xml</batsSuiteFile>
    <smokeSuiteFile>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/SmokeTests.xml</smokeSuiteFile>

    <!-- Default suite files if not being specified from mvn command line -->
    <defaultSuiteFiles>${batsSuiteFile},${smokeSuiteFile}</defaultSuiteFiles>
    <suiteFile>${defaultSuiteFiles}</suiteFile>
</properties>
```

Then in the plugin section...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
       <suiteXmlFiles>
          <!-- Suite file injection parameter from command line -->
          <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
       </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If nothing is specified from the command line it will fall back and default to the 2 suites specified above in the properties section.
Then if you want to kick off a specified set of suite files you can do:

```
mvn test -DsuiteFile=test1.xml,test2.xml
```

Surprisingly from the maven docs you expect that the arg suiteXmlFiles should just override this from the command line and should just accept a comma delimited list of testng xmls
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#suiteXmlFiles

If anyone has any other better way please share.

Comment: other way is to run below set of commands one after the other        mvn -D tests ${path}/test1 test ,                                                 mvn -D tests ${path}/test2 test  and dependency is                                   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
       <suiteXmlFiles>
          <!-- Suite file injection parameter from command line -->
          <suiteXmlFile>${tests}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
       </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Comment: Use `-Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles` instead. See my answer below.

Comment: @norbertpy this example also uses that variable :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groups](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#groups) parameter or specify -Dgroups=... in the command line:

> (TestNG/JUnit47 provider with JUnit4.8+ only) Groups for this test.
>   Only classes/methods/etc decorated with one of the groups specified
>   here will be included in test run, if specified. For JUnit, this
>   parameter forces the use of the 4.7 provider This parameter is ignored
>   if the suiteXmlFiles parameter is specified. .

Comment: I mentioned it that I don't want to use groups as it breaks test result report and is not flexible enough anyway

Comment: Flexible or not, but that's your only choice. It can be as flexible as granular your groups are. Of course besides running individual tests.