# Run TestNg suiteXmlFiles

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

We have a maven project with a testng.xml file where we have definied our suiteXmlFiles.
Below is our testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestingSuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="CaseCreationGui">
        <classes>
            <class name="selenium.CaseCreationGui" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
    <test name="CaseCreationHeadless">
        <classes>
            <class name="selenium.CaseCreationHeadless" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

In our POM.xml we have added the maven-surefire-plugin in order to execute our Tests. Below is a profile added in our POM.xml:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>selenium-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>CaseCreationGui.java</include>
                            <include>CaseCreationHeadless.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

In order to run our SuiteXMLFile we are running the below command where "selenium-tests" is the profile id defined in POM.

```
mvn clean test -U -P selenium-tests
```

The above command is successful.

We have seen in other posts that we can run our SuiteXMLFile by using the below command but unfortunately it is not working for us:

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml
```

We prefer to use the latter command in order to avoid updating the profiles of the POM.xml frequently whenever we add or remove new Suites.

Any ideas why the above command is not working ? Are we missing something ?

Thank you

Comment: why u have hardcoded the value of suiteXmlFile in ur pom ?

Comment: <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile> could work in your case. in general: <suiteXmlFile>${name}</suiteXmlFile> and -Dname

Comment: can you please share error trace ?

Comment: Please refer this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397315/how-to-parametrize-maven-surefire-plugin-so-i-can-choose-which-testng-suites-to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parametrize Maven surefire plugin so I can choose which TestNG suites to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397315/how-to-parametrize-maven-surefire-plugin-so-i-can-choose-which-testng-suites-to)