# Maven command to run a single Testng.xml

Tags: testng, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using Surefire Plugin, and I have a suite like this:

```
 <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suites/testng1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suites/testng2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
 </suiteXmlFiles>
```

If I execute this command:

```
mvn clean test
```

then both xml files are executed.  Now I want to run only `testng2.xml`, so I specify its path in this command:

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=/src/test/resources/suites/testng2.xml
```

but it doesn't work, because both testng1.xml and testng2.xml are again executed.

Am I missing something? I use Maven v3.5. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```

And in the command line:

`mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/suites/testng2.xml`

This code 'replaces' the variable ${suiteXmlFile} with the value provided.

Now if you want to have a default suite in your pom.xml which is executed when you do `mvn test`, but is overriden if you do `mvn test executeAnotherSuiteInsteadOfDefault`, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13829933/5494070.