# Unable to execute xml file in CircleCI

Tags: java, github, selenium-webdriver, circleci

I am new to CircleCI tool with Selenium Automation. I have updated my project in Github. While passing through Circle CI, it has passed all steps except where it has to execute Desktop.xml file for test execution. Here is how my `config.yml` file looks like:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.4.0
machine:
  environment:
    LT_USERNAME: "LT_USERNAME"
    LT_ACCESS_KEY: "LT_ACCESS_KEY"


jobs:
  image/cimg/openjdk
    docker:
      - image: cimg/openjdk:11.0
   
steps:

  - checkout
  - run:
      name: Check Version
      command: |
        mvn --version
        java -version
  - run:
      name: Build
      command: mvn -B -DskipTests clean package

  # Run your tests!
  - run:
      name: Desktop
      command: mvn test -D suite=src/test/resources/desktop.xml

workflows:
  sample: # This is the name of the workflow, feel free to change it to better match your workflow.
    # Inside the workflow, you define the jobs you want to run.
    jobs:
      - build-and-test
```

It is failing in Desktop step in CircleCI while merging my changes from my branch to Main branch. Following is the error I see in CircleCI tool:

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-testng-utils/2.22.2/surefire-testng-utils-2.22.2.jar (27 kB at 944 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-grouper/2.22.2/surefire-grouper-2.22.2.jar (40 kB at 1.3 MB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-testng/2.22.2/surefire-testng-2.22.2.jar (44 kB at 1.3 MB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.245 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-16T05:39:59Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project Zerocater-UI-Automation: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/circleci/project/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Suite file /home/circleci/project/{suiteXmlFile} is not a valid file
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Suite file /home/circleci/project/{suiteXmlFile} is not a valid file
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:656)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Please suggest a suitable help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be `Suite file /home/circleci/project/{suiteXmlFile} is not a valid file`.

Check your `pom.xml` and see if `suiteXmlFile` is set, [as in here](https://suiteXmlFile), or in this [CircleCI test project](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-perform-test-automation-with-circleci).

It should reference a file within your project repository, as seen in [Using Suite XML Files](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#using-suite-xml-files).

The [OP Saurabh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6815981/saurabh) refers in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74455864/unable-to-execute-xml-file-in-circleci/74456206?noredirect=1#comment131437747_74456206) to "[How to parametrize Maven surefire plugin so I can choose which TestNG suites to run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31441587/6309)" in order to put the correct value to `suiteXmlFile`.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Though I resolved it by referring to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397315/how-to-parametrize-maven-surefire-plugin-so-i-can-choose-which-testng-suites-to
But this is way more helpful for me in future problems.

Comment: @Saurabh Perfect, well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.